# Is there way to check whether a Form has a Form Border? (by handle)

Tags: c#, winforms, handle, formborderstyle

I want to check whether a form has a Form Border by its handle.
And, the handle is from the another Application.

How can I handle this?
Please help me.. Thanks!

Comment: Windows Forms? Native Win32? Something else? -- Please note that C# as a *language* doesn't know anything about handles and windows etc. so your question must be about a particular UI framework. Please tag accordingly.

Comment: P.S. Win32 does not even distinguish between windows and controls. Technically, they are all "windows", albeit ones with differing attributes.

Comment: hmm.. i Just want to know whether it has a FormBorder or not. And the handle is from another Application.

Comment: @jn4kim: Then that should be your question.  As stakx said, controls themselves are windows.

Comment: @jn4kim: My question still stands. It seems you're talking about Winforms. But what if that other application is native code, or WPF? The notion of a `FormBorder` *might* be meaningless with these...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
extern static int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
const int WS_BORDER = 0x00800000;  // thin border
const int WS_THICKFRAME = 0x00040000;  // sizing (thick) border

public static bool NativeWindowHasBorder(IntPtr hWnd)
{
     return (GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_STYLE) & (WS_BORDER | WS_THICKFRAME)) != 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `GetWindowLongPtr` if you use `IntPtr`? Or `GetWindowLong` if you use `Int32`? Or: Why the `.ToInt64()` conversion?

Comment: @stakx Yes. I couldn't remember how to get window styles off the top of my head and pasted that from someone who did it wrong. I've corrected it.

Comment: `GetWindowLongPtr` is not necessary as the WS_BORDER and WS_THICKFRAME bits are both within the first 32.

Answer (score 0):

`Control`s themselves don't actually have a handle. `Control.Handle` actually returns it's parent window's `.Handle`.

From [MSDN for `Control.Handle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.handle.aspx):

> Gets the window handle that the control is bound to.

If you look at the decompiled source for `Control`, you'll see:

```
internal IntPtr HandleInternal
{
  get
  {
    return this.window.Handle;
  }
}
```

---

**Edit**

What I've stated above is completely incorrect. I'm leaving it for historical sake.

One can prove this very easily by putting a `Button` on a `Form`, and looking at the `IntPtr Handle` value for them. They are different.

Comment: Uhm, is it a good idea / legal to post decompiled framework code...? I don't want to FUD you but this might be worth a thought. PS: That decompiled code is almost meaningless without more knowledge about what `this.window` mean.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer but this is not what i want to know, i think i did not write the question correctly

Comment: @stakx I think it's pretty clear that the Control itself doesn't have a handle, and instead, it's returning it's parent window's handle. Just as the MSDN text describes.

Comment: @Jonathon: -1. I believe your answer is incorrect, and I am certain that controls have a handle, too. Your answer actually supports this: Controls are technically also "windows" in Win32 API parlance (and Winforms is based on Win32), so I think you're mistaken when you assume that "window handle" means "parent window handle". Instead the `Control.Handle` "window handle" refers to the internal `HWND` of the control.

Comment: @stakx You are absolutely correct. I just did a quick test, and indeed, the values of `IntPtr Handle` are different between a `Form` and a `Button` on that `Form`. Having used Spy++ 100's of times before, I should have thought of this.